# How to send a query with DateTime to Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to do something like this

```
Datetime date
SendCommand("select * from schools where date= "+ date );
```

and it is not working... Any ideas?

Comment: What data access technology are you using to communicate with the database?  That technology *should* have a way to add parameters to a query, rather than try to manually concatenate values as strings.  Use a parameter to add your value to the query.

Comment: **NEVER** concatenate data into the query. Use parameters, which also have a built-in datetime type.

Comment: you are 100% right about that but in this case it happens to be very convinient to send it this way somehow

Comment: @sunsunsun2200 it honestly doesn't matter how conveniently you can do the wrong thing :)

Comment: Given that it doesn't work in this case, and you had to post to SO to get an answer, it's not very convenient.  But even in the convenient case, you are letting yourself open to something called _SQL Injection_, particularly if you are concatenating something you obtained from a user.  Take a look at https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, "parameters". But: correctly using parameters is hard, so: tools like Dapper will help you. Consider:

```cs
using Dapper; // also needs a NuGet package reference to Dapper
//...
DateTime date = ...
var schools = connection.Query<School>("select * from schools where date=@date",
    new { date }).AsList();
```

Where `School` is a class that looks a lot like your table. Everything in the `new {...}` is the named and typed parameters to send. Dapper deals with the how for you.

Comment: You don't have to use Dapper to get the benefit of using parameters.  You can do it with straight-up ADO.NET as well.  Dapper just makes doing this sort of thing much easier.  @MarcGravell should know, he's one of Dapper's prime maintainers

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date;
string datest = string.Empty;
datest = date.Year + "-" + date.Month + "-" + date.Day;
```

if you use these line it will work it might not be the best practice but i will leave it here in case someone needs it

ο νικος σας κατούρησε